# Solution for $x'(t)=f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb R$, with $x(0)=x(1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $x'(t)=f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb R$, What can we say about the solution if $x(t)$ if it satisfies $x(0)=x(1)$?

Here I am getting $x'(t)=f(x) \Rightarrow \int_0^t  x'(t) dt=\int_0^tf(x(t))dt \Rightarrow x(t)-x(0)=\int_0^tf(x(t))dt$

$\Rightarrow x(t)=x(0)+\int_0^tf(x(t))dt$

Is it useful to proceed?

Comment: What happens if you try $$\frac{dx}{f(x)} = dt$$ and so on?

Comment: It means it is 1-periodic.

Comment: Sorry Sir, I am not getting how it is 1-periodic and how can we proceed $\frac{dx}{f(x)}=dt$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no non-trivial periodic solutions in a one-dimensional first-order autonomous ODE $x'(t)=f(x(t))$.

- The roots of the right side are stationary or equilibrium points (calling them fixed points leads to misunderstandings with the discrete fixed-point equation). These roots give all rise to constant solutions.
- As the right side is differentiable, the uniqueness theorem implies that these constant solutions are hard boundaries for all the other solutions, they can not be crossed, not even reached.
- Between the roots, the function $f$ has a constant sign. Any solution in such an interval is strictly monotonous with the direction imposed by the sign of $f$. The limit of the solution is either infinity or one of the stationary points.

So there remains only one possibility to achieve the claimed behavior of the solution.