# If a function $f: \mathbb {R }\to \mathbb {R }$ is differentiable and satisfies $ f'(t) = | f(t) −t |$, then $t \to f (t) - t$ has at most a zero.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a little problem showing that: if a function $f: \mathbb {R }\to \mathbb {R }$ is differentiable and satisfies $ f'(t) = | f(t) −t |$, then $t \to f (t) - t$   has at most a zero

An idea please

Comment: no I made a mistake, I forgot to say that he has at most a zero

Comment: "an idea please" gets bad attention on this site, which i guess you know from having >900 rep and a couple of closed questions. This question right now has 3 close votes. Know that if you keep getting closed questions, at some point the website will prevent you from asking new questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to give the combination of terms in the claim a function name, $g(t)=f(t)-t$. Then
$$
g'(t)=|g(t)|-1
$$
is autonomous and locally Lipschitz, so [the usual conclusions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3856695/solution-for-xt-fx) apply.